# Opengl : Optimization in changing view matrix when using VBO?

Tags: opengl, camera, shader

I'm doing some refactoring, trying to use VBOs and my own shaders to display some graphical objects (let's say 1000 spheres) instead of display lists.

For the moment, my objects are rendered nicely in around 100ms, but when I try to move the camera (changing the "viewmatrix" which is an uniform variable of my shader), I have to redraw all my objects, which last an other 100ms... Is there a way to reduce this time by changing only the uniform variable "viewmatrix" ?

Note : in the original code (the one which was using display list), after a movement of camera, the scene was redrawn in less than 10 ms, by using the function "glCallList"... I would like to have similar results with VBO, but it's not the case yet... I must have missed something...

Here is some samples of my code :

The drawer (the method "drawMethod" is executed 1000 times, one for each sphere) :

```
    public void draw() {

        shaderProgram.start();

        transformationMatrix = TransformationMatrix.createTransformationMatrix(new Vector3f(0,0,0), 0, 0, 0, 1);
        shaderProgram.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        shaderProgram.loadViewMatrix(renderer.camera);

        Light light = new Light(new Vector3f(50,50,100),new Vector3f(1,1,1));
        shaderProgram.loadLight(light);

        for (DrawingEntity entity : listOfEntities) {
            drawMethod(entity);
        }

        shaderProgram.stop();

        mapEntities.clear();

    }
    private void genericDrawMethod(DrawingEntity entity) {
            shaderProgram.enableNormal();
            float shineDamper = (float) entity.getMaterial().getShineDamper();
            float reflectivity = (float) entity.getMaterial().getReflectivity();
            shaderProgram.loadShineVariables(shineDamper,reflectivity);
            shaderProgram.loadAmbientLight(new Vector3f(
                        (float) renderer.data.getAmbientLightColor().getRed() / 255f,
                        (float) renderer.data.getAmbientLightColor().getGreen() / 255f,
                        (float) renderer.data.getAmbientLightColor().getBlue() / 255f));

            float[] vertices = entity.getVertices();
            float[] colors = entity.getColors();
            float[] idxBuffer = entity.getIndices();
            float[] normals = entity.getNormals();


            // VERTICES POSITIONS BUFFER
            storeDataInAttributeList(ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE_IDX,VERTICES_IDX,vertices);

            // COLORS BUFFER
            shaderProgram.disableTexture();
            storeDataInAttributeList(ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_IDX,COLOR_IDX,colors);

            // NORMAL BUFFER
            storeDataInAttributeList(ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE_IDX,NORMAL_IDX,normals);

            // INDEX BUFFER
            int[] intIdxBuff = new int[idxBuffer.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < idxBuffer.length ; i++) {
                intIdxBuff[i] = (int) idxBuffer[i];
            }
            IntBuffer ibIdxBuff = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(intIdxBuff);
            // Select the VBO, GPU memory data, to use for colors
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[IDX_BUFF_IDX]);
            int numBytes = idxBuffer.length * 4;
            gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, numBytes, ibIdxBuff, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            ibIdxBuff.rewind();

            // draw triangles
            gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, idxBuffer.length, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

            releaseVAOMemory();
        }

        private void storeDataInAttributeList(int shaderAttributeNumber, int bufferAttributeNumber, float[] data) {
            int coordinateSize = 0;
            switch (shaderAttributeNumber) {
            // recognize the type of VAO to determine the size of the coordinates
                case ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_IDX : coordinateSize = 4; break; // r, g, b, a
                case ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE_IDX : coordinateSize = 3; break; // x, y, z
                case ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE_IDX : coordinateSize = 3; break; // x, y, z
                case ShaderProgram.UVMAPPING_ATTRIBUTE_IDX : coordinateSize = 2; break; // u, v
            }
            FloatBuffer fbData = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(data);
            // Select the VBO, GPU memory data, to use for data
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[bufferAttributeNumber]);
            int numBytes = data.length * 4;
            gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numBytes, fbData, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            fbData.rewind(); // It is OK to release CPU after transfer to GPU
            // Associate Vertex attribute 1 with the last bound VBO
            gl.glVertexAttribPointer(shaderAttributeNumber, coordinateSize,
                                GL2.GL_FLOAT, false /* normalized? */, 0 /* stride */,
                                0 /* The bound VBO data offset */);
            gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderAttributeNumber);
            listOfVAOUsed.add(shaderAttributeNumber);
        }

        private void releaseVAOMemory() {
            for (Integer vao : listOfVAOUsed) {
                gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vao);
            }
            listOfVAOUsed.clear();
        }
```

My vertex shader :

```
#if __VERSION__ >= 130
    #define attribute in
    #define varying out
#endif

#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
#endif

uniform mat4    transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4    projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4    viewMatrix;
uniform vec3    lightPosition;
uniform float   useNormals; // 0 for no, 1 for yes

attribute vec3  attribute_Position;
attribute vec4  attribute_Color;
attribute vec3  attribute_Normal;
attribute vec3  attribute_TextureCoords;

varying vec4    varying_Color;
varying vec3    surfaceNormal;
varying vec3    toLightVector;
varying vec3    toCameraVector;
varying vec2    pass_textureCoords;
varying float   varying_useNormals;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(attribute_Position,1.0);

    varying_Color = attribute_Color;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;

    varying_useNormals = useNormals;

    if (useNormals > 0.5)
    {
        surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(attribute_Normal,0.0)).xyz;
        toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
        toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

        pass_textureCoords = attribute_TextureCoords;
    }
}
```

And my fragment shader :

```
#if __VERSION__ >= 130
    #define varying in
    out vec4 mgl_FragColor;
    #define texture2D texture
    #define gl_FragColor mgl_FragColor
#endif

#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;
#endif

varying   vec4    varying_Color;
varying   vec3    surfaceNormal;
varying   vec3    toLightVector;
varying   vec3    toCameraVector;
varying   vec2    pass_textureCoords;
varying   float   varying_useNormals;

uniform   vec3    ambientLight;
uniform   vec3    lightColor;
uniform   float   shineDamper;
uniform   float   reflectivity;
uniform   sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform   float   useTexture; // 0 for no, 1 for yes

void main (void)
{
    vec4 inputColor = varying_Color;

    if (varying_useNormals > 0.5)
    {
        if (useTexture > 0.5)
        {
            inputColor = texture(textureSampler,pass_textureCoords);
        }

        vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
        if (!gl_FrontFacing)
        {
            unitNormal = -normalize(surfaceNormal);
        }

        vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

        float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal,unitLightVector);

        float brightnessR = max(nDot1,ambientLight.x);
        float brightnessG = max(nDot1,ambientLight.y);
        float brightnessB = max(nDot1,ambientLight.z);
        //float brightness = max(nDot1,0.0);
        vec3 diffuse = vec3(brightnessR*lightColor.x,brightnessG*lightColor.y,brightnessB*lightColor.z);

        vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
        vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
        vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection,unitNormal);

        float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
        specularFactor = max(specularFactor,0.0);
        float damperFactor = pow(specularFactor,shineDamper);
        vec3 finalSpecular = damperFactor * reflectivity * lightColor;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse,1.0) * inputColor + vec4(finalSpecular,1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = inputColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main performance bottleneck is that you are uploading all data in every frame to the gpu memory. Create and fill the vbo once and then use them in every frame.

Comment: Mmm... Indeed, it works better now. Thank you ! :)